# How to prepopulate Email and Password using devise like we do in Password prompt after log out?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, passwords

I am using devise(1.3.4), and i want to store the email and password of the user like we do in the password prompt in standard browsers. If i log out and then try logs in i want to see the email and password pre-populated in the fields Is there any possibility in devise to do this?

Comment: It's the browser's responsibility to pre-populate fields. Devise  encrypts passwords by default so there's absolutely no way to do what you want unless you store the passwords in clear-text in the database - which is something you should **never** do.

Comment: Yes i know that, but this is my client's requirement...:(

Comment: Store details in cookies, when user logout and check it if there is cookies print in browser.